# instead of summing the two values, it just repeats it

Tags: python, if-statement, sum

my code in python is supposed to sum the two variables and return a value, but it keeps returning the two numbers together:

```
A = input("insert a value: ")
B = input("insert another value: ")
if A >= B:
    R == A + B 
    print ("this is the result", R)
else:
    R == A - B
    print ("this is the result", R)


input 1: A=1 and B=1
output 1: R=11

input 2: A=2 and B=1
output 2: R=21
```

Comment: `input()` returns strings (assuming you're using Python 3).  When you add strings in Python you get concatenated strings.  `"fred" + "bob"` returns `"fredbob"`. `"1" + "2"` returns `"12"`.

Comment: `R == ...` looks like a typo, double `=` for comparison and single `=` for assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input()` returns a string (`str`) object, so when you try to add A and B together, they end up being concatenated.

You need to cast the result from `input()` to an integer (`int`). Try something like this instead:

```
A = int(input("insert a value: "))
B = int(input("insert another value: "))
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't write python code, but you need to cast the input from type String to Int

```
A_INPUT = input("insert a value: ")
B_INPUT = input("insert another value: ")

A = int(A_INPUT)
B = int(B_INPUT)

if A >= B:
    R == A + B 
    print ("this is the result", R)
else:
    R == A - B
    print ("this is the result", R)
```

[https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-convert-string-to-int-how-to-cast-a-string-in-python/#:~:text=To%20convert%2C%20or%20cast%2C%20a,int(%22str%22)%20](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-convert-string-to-int-how-to-cast-a-string-in-python/#:%7E:text=To%20convert%2C%20or%20cast%2C%20a,int(%22str%22)%20).

Comment: Minor nit.  Prompt asks for a value so valid input may be something like `2.7` and `3.8`.